# WordPress Images Are Not showing After Changing Directory Name

Tags: images

After changing WordPress directory name, all WordPress images are not showing in backend/ admin and frontend, not even themes images. I have flushed permanent links, updated URL and uploads folder paths, but nothing seems to solve the problem. Here is how WordPress Media Library looks like now: https://prnt.sc/g1k8qz

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi. You should also replace the old paths with new paths by doing a search replace. The [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin is a good one to start with.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help! But my question would be how different is that plugin you're suggesting to "Automatic Domain Change"? That's what I used to automatically update the URLs. Here its https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-domain-changer/